# How to list all files in named directory, file type included?

Tags: linux, shell

Right now i am able to list all the files using -l, and i can break it down to filename etc. using awk

e.g

`ls -l ~/directory1 | awk '{print $9, $5}'`

which returns something like

`filename filesize`

How could i also display the file type?

Comment: what do you mean by "file type"? the one returned by `file(1)`? the first column of `ls -l` already tells if the file is a directory, character device, regular file, etc.

Comment: You might consider using [`stat`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=stat&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html) instead of [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Note that your snippet will fail for file names with spaces in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
find . -exec stat --format="%n %s %F" {} \;
```

This finds all items in the current directory, change to suit your needs,
and runs the [stat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command on each item. 
The `%n` represents the item's name. 
The `%s` is the item's size.  The `%F` is the item's type.

The [`find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command has a `-type f` option to process only plain files
and a `-type d` option for directories.

Comment: Hi, thanks this is what i was looking for, is there anyway i could get it to only display the files and not the directory itself aswell?

Comment: The find command has a "-type f" to only process files.  "-type d" is for directories.  You can probably do something like "-type d -prune -or -type f" to have it skip directories.